# On the go - can it refer to something being consumed?

Tags: phrase-usage, idiom-meaning

Dictionaries define 'on the go'

mostly as:

- very busy (Cambridge)
- very busy or active (Macmillan)
- very active or busy (Oxford)
- to be very active and busy (Oxford Learner's)
- constantly or restlessly active (MW)
- very active or busy (MW Learner's)
- active and energetic / in constant motion or action (Collins)
- very busy doing a lot of things (Longman)
- actively traveling; busy; moving often (Wiktionary)

and also as:

- in the process of being produced (Cambridge)
- in the process of being done or produced (Macmillan)
- happening or going (MW Learner's)
- if you have something on the go, you have started it and are busy doing it (Longman)
- in progress; having started (Wiktionary)

and occasionally as:

- quickly while doing some other activity (Macmillan)

---

Several times, however, I have encountered the following kind of usage:

> *There is always a bottle or glass of something **on the go** at my desk or with me!* ([source](https://www.stellamuse.com/detox-to-empower-you-divine-body-temple/))
>
> *Chain-smoking chimp who's so addicted he has two cigarettes **on the go** at once* ([source](https://www.dailymail.co.uk/news/article-2296405/Chain-smoking-chimp-cigarettes.html))

The dictionary definitions do not seem to cover this meaning.

The second group of definitions comes closest, but even that is a rather poor fit (a drink or a cigarette done / produced / happening / going?).

Even the sentences provided as examples (on the dictionary sites) use 'on the go' in connection with *projects* and *inititatives*,  not drinks and cigs.

Is this another meaning for 'on the go' not covered by the dictionaries? Or perhaps not even proper usage?

Thank you.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/103221/discussion-on-question-by-bepe-on-the-go-can-it-refer-to-something-being-consu).

Answer (score 1):

The bottle or glassful are always  *in the process of being consumed* (as distinct from an unopened bottle kept in the desk drawer for a special occasion).

The chimp's two cigarettes were both being smoked at once.